# How to echo Wordpress default thumbnail via php inside php if else

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey guys i have this code

```
<?php  $jthumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
 if ($jthumb> "0")
  {
echo $jthumb;
}
  else
 {
 echo "http://placehold.it/350x250&text= Jedcore";
  }
 ?>);background-attachment:fixed;">
```

What i wanted to do is to replace the 
`http://placehold.it/350x250&text= Jedcore` with an image inside my wordpress theme like 
`<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/theimage.png`

But i just cant replace it liek that i will prompt an error,

I'm no expert with php :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
echo '<img src="'. bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/img.jpg" alt="">';
```

Answer (score 0):

try after this 
change

```
echo "http://placehold.it/350x250&text= Jedcore";
```

to

```
echo get_bloginfo('template_url').'images/theimage.png';
```

Comment: Thanks this works like a charm, what i did is include a php file that has the <?php bloginfo_url('template_url')/images/theimage.png

Comment: but now im using your code its much mo easy :D thanks